# How to have a date type column for ProColumn's valueType but searched in dateRange type in ProTable?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd design, especially ProTable. I have a column that has a date type. But in search, I want it to be searched in dateRange type. This is a very common user experience, users search in the form of between dates, not in a particular date. Is there a way to do it? I searched a lot but there is not much resources regarding ProTable itself. If someone had the same experience and a solution for it, could you please share it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while ago. Solved by using `search` and then `transform`:

```
 {
    title: 'Pick a period',
    dataIndex: 'datetime',
    valueType: 'dateRange',
    search: {
      transform: (value) => {
        return {
          startDate: value[0].replaceAll('-', ''),
          endDate: value[1].replaceAll('-', ''),
        }
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a fieldProps function, and return with the config and the format you want.

```
{
    title: 'Pick a period',
    dataIndex: 'datetime',
    valueType: 'dateRange',
    fieldProps(form, config) {
        return {
          ...config,
          format: "DD-MM-YYYY",
        }
      },
  }
```